# Positional comparison in multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create multiple lists that are dependent on the previous list.

So for example list 1 would read a specific file and return either a number or the boolean false based on a comparison.

The second list would then compare the number that appears in the same position as those in the previous list (if the value from the previous list was not false) and return the value or false based on the same comparison as the first list

I created a function that carries out these comparisons and creates a list

```
def generic_state_machine(file,obs_nums):
    return file.ix[:,0][obs_nums] if file.ix[:,0][obs_nums] > 0.2 else False
```

Note: obs_nums looks at the position of the item in a list

I then created the lists that look at different files

```
session_to_leads = []
lead_to_opps = []

for i in range(1,len(a)):
     session_to_leads.append(generic_state_machine(file=a,obs_nums=i))
     lead_to_opps.append(generic_state_machine(file=b,obs_nums=i)) if session_to_leads != False else lead_to_opps.append(False)
```

Given

```
a = pd.DataFrame([0,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8])
b = pd.DataFrame([0.7,0.51,0.3,0.7,0.2])
```

I managed to sort out the initial error I encountered, the only problem now is that list lead_to_opps is not dependent on session_to_leads so if there is a False value in position 1, lead_to_opps will not automatically return a False in the same position. So assuming that random.uniform(0,1) generates 0.5 all the time, this is my current outcome:

```
session_to_leads = [False,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8]
lead_to_opps = [0.7,0.51,False,0.7,False]
```

whereas my desired outcome would be

```
session_to_leads = [False,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8]
lead_to_opps = [False,0.51,False,0.7,False]
```

Answer (score 0):

"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

This is not an error, this is basically "based on the previous error, this new error occurred.

Please post the error before this one, it will help a lot.
Also, I did not got what is [obs_nums]

Comment: obs_num is the position of the item in the list

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Requests for more information to be posted should go in the comments, not in an answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
file.ix[:, 1][obs_nums]
```

Is the problem, assuming .ix behaves like .loc (it seems .ix is deprecated)

```
>>> help(pd.Dataframe.loc)

Allowed inputs are...

- A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'

warning:: Note that contrary to usual python slices, 
**both** the start and the stop are included
```

It's a bit difficult to follow the indexing but do you need to slice at all? Would just:

```
file.loc[obs_nums]
```

return the number or Boolean you are looking for?